# {"Invalid column name 'SessionStatus_Id'."}. Column `Id` got prefixed with table name?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I have the following model class. The program uses EF V6.2.0

```
public partial class SessionStatus
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public SessionStatus()
    {
        Sessions = new HashSet<Session>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("Id", TypeName ="TinyInt")] // No effect
    public byte Id { get; set; } // Becomes SessionStatus_Id for DB operations

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

And `Session` class is

```
public partial class Session
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Session()
    {
        SessionMessages = new HashSet<SessionMessage>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }

    // ......

    public virtual SessionStatus SessionStatus { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code

```
        using (var ctx = new ProcessContext())
        {
            ctx.Sessions.Add(new Session { Uid = guid, //...... });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

got the error of

> {"Invalid column name 'SessionStatus_Id'."}

The database table `SessionStatus` has the column name of `Id` stead of `SessionStatus_Id` (Table column `SessionStatus_Id` doesn't exist). Why EF prefixed the column name with table name? Even the attribute `[Column("Id", TypeName ="TinyInt")]` doesn't help?

Comment: SessionStatus_Id is not the PK of the SessionStatus table, but the FK pointing from "Session" to "SessionStatus". I don't see the FK you intend to use for this relationship - if it isnt meant to be reflected in the database model, ignore the direct and inverse navigation properties. If it is, you should provide the correct FK column and adjust the mapping accordingly.

Comment: Actually, `SessionStatus_Id` doesn't exist.

Comment: @ca9163d9 have you done a full assembly build search for `SessionStatus_Id`. Possibly related but I've come across EF sometimes appending prefixes to column names. Eg, If I had a table Called "User" and I had a column within that table called "User" EF would create it as "User_1".

Comment: obviously. Code first conventions name the FK column {OtherTableName}+"_"+"Id". It won't be in your code unless you named one property exactly that, but it would appear in the table if you let EF create the DB for you. The FK name comes from EF code first naming conventions, if your existing DB schema doesn't match code first conventions, you'll have to adjust your mapping.

Comment: @slee423 this is incorrect. The column name "User" is possible in a table named "User", the usual identifier would be [dbname].[dbo].[User].[User]. Your described naming behavior occurs however, if there would be a duplicate name otherwise, so if the table "User" has a column "User" and the type had a property "User" not mapped to this column. Then the table user would have both columns "User" and "User_1".

Answer (score 0):

Try change temporarily the name instead of `Id` and you will get answer...